# Convert only certain rows from long to wide in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataframe that begins like this:

```
schools <- structure(list(
    school = c("Griffith Elementary", "Griffith Elementary", "Griffith Elementary", "Griffith Elementary", "Debs Elementary", "Debs Elementary", "Debs Elementary", "Debs Elementary", "Griffith Magnet Elementary", "Griffith Magnet Elementary", "Griffith Magnet Elementary", "Griffith Magnet Elementary"), 
    year = c(2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019), 
    unique_id = c(25, 25, 25, 25, 14, 14, 14, 14, 25, 25, 25, 25), 
    enrollment = c(100, 105, 115, 110, 135, 140, 150, 145, 50, 50, 55, 55))) %>% 
    as.data.frame()
```

And looks like this:

[image]

What I would like to do is to use `pivot_wider` to transform only the rows with the same unique ID. So my desired dataframe looks like this:

[image]

Is this possible? Any help appreicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `rleid` from `data.table` on the 'unique_id' column to generate distinct ids when the adjacent values are not similar, then grouped by 'unique_id', change the 'new' column to create sequential values using `match`, create a sequence column with `row_number()` to account for duplicate elements before doing the `pivot_wider` to reshape into 'wide'

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
schools %>%
    mutate(new = rleid(unique_id)) %>% 
    group_by(unique_id) %>%
    mutate(new = match(new, unique(new))) %>% 
    group_by(new) %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = new,
     values_from = c(school, year, unique_id, enrollment), names_sep = "") %>%
    select(-rn) %>% 
    select(order(rowid(str_remove(names(.), "\\d+"))))
```

-ouptut

```
# A tibble: 8 x 8
  school1             year1 unique_id1 enrollment1 school2                    year2 unique_id2 enrollment2
  <chr>               <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>                      <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>
1 Griffith Elementary  2016         25         100 Griffith Magnet Elementary  2016         25          50
2 Griffith Elementary  2017         25         105 Griffith Magnet Elementary  2017         25          50
3 Griffith Elementary  2018         25         115 Griffith Magnet Elementary  2018         25          55
4 Griffith Elementary  2019         25         110 Griffith Magnet Elementary  2019         25          55
5 Debs Elementary      2016         14         135 <NA>                          NA         NA          NA
6 Debs Elementary      2017         14         140 <NA>                          NA         NA          NA
7 Debs Elementary      2018         14         150 <NA>                          NA         NA          NA
8 Debs Elementary      2019         14         145 <NA>                          NA         NA          NA
```